# Why do methods inside a file with return still work?

Tags: php

If you have two files, `file-a.php` and `file-b.php`

`file-a.php` contents:

```
require 'file-b.php';
my_test( 'hi' );
```

and `file-b.php` contents:

```
function my_test( $text ) {
  echo $text; 
}
```

Then "hi" is echo'd normally as expected.

But if in `file-b.php` you add a return on the first line, like this:

```
return;
function my_test( $text ) {
  echo $text; 
}
```

then nothing is echo'd, but there is also no error notice saying that "my_test" method was not declared anywhere.
Why is this happening? I expected an error of undeclared function.

Edit: To clarify. If I then make file-a.php contents:

```
require 'file-b.php';
my_test( 'hi' );
my_second_test_that_doesnt_exist( 'hi' );
```

Then I do get a 'Call to undefined function "my_second_test_that_doesnt_exist"'

Comment: enable error reporting

Comment: Please see my edit where I elaborate further.

Comment: Why are you doing return on global scope?
It's will be stop the script run and not define your function.

Comment: Both PHP 5.5.38 and 7.0.10 give me a "hi" with the top-level return in the second file...

Comment: I concur with @Siguza I get a `Hi` from PHP5.4/5.5/5.6/7.0/7.1 when the `return;` is the first line in `file-b.php`

Comment: Really? That's weird! On 5.6 the moment I add the return, the hi stops echo'ing and no error. Need to investigate that.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning from the file. So everything under the line "return" isn't executed. BUT it gets noticed by PHP, so even if you can't call it, PHP knows that it exists so it won't throw an error.